# App Engine Channel API's Javascript Client Isn't Using my onError Callback

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, channel-api

I'm using App Engine's Channel API to maintain a connection between a Chrome extension and an App Engine app. You can see my Channel-related code here: https://github.com/2cloud/Chrome/blob/3fe70262ef69ae8286a057055f4108760560c47e/socket.js (The app is open source, so you can check out the repository to get an idea of how it all fits together)

My issue is, for some reason, the 401 error that App Engine throws when a token expires isn't being sent to my onError listener. I've tried just logging the error object from within onError, outside of an if statement, and still got nothing. My conclusion was that onError isn't getting called when a 401 is thrown, as the documentation says it's supposed to.

Has anyone else seen this error? Does anyone else have an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I never noticed it before because I use a handler at '/_ah/channel/disconnected/' to deal with broken connections, but neither socket.onerror or socket.onclose ever seem to be called.

Comment: I'm not sure how the handler would allow me to keep a persistent connection alive. Could you clarify? Also, I'm not sure when this regression was introduced, but it definitely worked at one point.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to imply I was able to keep the connection alive.  I use channel_presence (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections) to keep the application aware of which channels are active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced this bug and started work fixing it. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5685